# Solidity Storage Pointers

Tags: solidity, blockchain, remix, ethereum-wallet-dapp, storage-pointer

```
contract X{

   uint256 public x=2;
   uint256[] public array= [9,8];
   
   function X(){}
   
   function getLength() public constant returns(uint256){
      return array.length;
   }
   
   function modifyArray( uint256 _index, uint256 _value){
      array[_index]= _value;
   }
   
   function popLength(){
      array.length--;
   }
}
```

Roman Storm shows in this video how to change the variable x with using storage pointers in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gUqHgFuSsqg with using the modifyArray-function at the end and I couldn't get it. Can someone explain in a detailed and simple way what is happening under the hood here. Thanks in advance. The code belongs to him(in the link).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't much to explain. An `uint256[] public array` in storage is organized as follow:

```
| length |   0   |   1   | ... | length-1 |
```

Each `|   X   |` represents a 32 bytes slot.

The problem was that old solidity version allowed an underflow when modifying the array's length.

For example `array` has 2 elements, so after calling `popLength()` two times length will be zero.

If called a third time it will be `115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639935` which is `2**256 - 1`.

So with `array[X]` you could write almost anywhere in the contract storage.